# Spring Integration combine path variables and post body in payload expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-el

Using an http inbound-gateway I am able to specify a payload-expression using SPEL that will access header, requestParams, and pathVariables.  How do I also include the body from a POST?  An example of what I currently have is

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway path="/document/{product}/{id}/blah"
                          supported-methods="GET"
                          request-channel="documentService.blah"
                          reply-channel="httpReplyChannel"
                          message-converters="jsonMessageConverter"
                          header-mapper="defaultHttpHeaderMapper"
                          payload-expression="new RequestDTO(
                                                 #pathVariables.product,
                                                 #pathVariables.id,
                                                 #requestParams['optionalParam'],
                                                 headers.get('headerKey')) />
```

That works fine, however I want to add an additional parameter to the RequestDTO constructor that is the actual post body (obviously I will change the method) and have it serialized into the appropriate type.

Is this possible?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. 
**payload-expression** uses an **EvaluationContext** with **HttpEntity** as **rootObject**,
**#requestParams** and **#pathVariables** variables.
So, if you change it to POST you can get a body!:

```
 payload-expression="new RequestDTO(
                         #pathVariables.product,
                         #pathVariables.id,
                         #requestParams['optionalParam'],
                         headers.get('headerKey'),
                         body)"
```

It is just because **HttpEntity** has that getter!

Comment: Artem, thanks, that clears up more than just the body.  I never understood what context the payload-expression used. I'm sure this is something I have skimmed over multiple times in the docs and it just didn't click.  Thanks for the complete answer!