# HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway PayloadExpression java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, dsl

I want to use `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway::setPayloadExpression` to map the request values to my model object. I found  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898816/spring-integration-combine-path-variables-and-post-body-in-payload-expression), but didn't manage to do the same with java config. If somebody can provide an example, it will be great.

My code:

```
    @Bean
    public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway httpViewGate() {
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway gateway = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway(true);
        RequestMapping requestMapping = new RequestMapping();
        requestMapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.GET);
        requestMapping.setPathPatterns("/foo");
        requestMapping.setProduces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        gateway.setRequestMapping(requestMapping);
        gateway.setRequestChannel(intConfig.viewFlowRequestChannel());
        gateway.setPayloadExpression(???); //what to do here
        gateway.setRequestPayloadType(ViewClientCriteria.class);// this may not be required
        return gateway;
    }
```

Also I'm interested if there is another more flexible way to do the same.

I use Spring Boot 1.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Expression payloadExpression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("...");
gateway.setPayloadExpression(payloadExpression);
```